# How to convert a pyspark data frame into multiple nested json

Tags: python, json, dataframe, pyspark, nested

I have a pyspark data frame that is populated from an SQL table with below field columns and their values .

```
transactionid   docname  docdetailfield1  docdetailfield2
1234             name1   name1detail1     name1detail2
1235             name2   name2detail1     name2detail2
```

I need to create a multi level nested json from the pyspark dataframe using pyspark.
is it possible ?

```
{
  "transactionid": "123",
  "docsection": {
    "docname": "name1",
    "docDetails": {
      "docdetailfield1": "name1detail1",
      "docdetailfield2": "name1detail2",
     
    }
  }
}
```

Tried splitting dataframe and grouping . I am getting individual json structure but not the nested json strcture as above .can any one help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pack the required columns into the `struct` type, then convert to json

```
section = F.struct('docname', F.struct('docdetailfield1', 'docdetailfield2').alias('docDetails'))
records = df.select('transactionid', section.alias('docSection')).toJSON()
```

---

```
records.collect()

['{"transactionid":1234,"docSection":{"docname":"name1","docDetails":{"docdetailfield1":"name1detail1","docdetailfield2":"name1detail2"}}}',
 '{"transactionid":1235,"docSection":{"docname":"name2","docDetails":{"docdetailfield1":"name2detail1","docdetailfield2":"name2detail2"}}}']
```

Comment: Thanks Shubham for the solution .This works . As next step is it possible to include this nested json as a new column in a data frame ?

Comment: its possible, you can just use `to_json`:  `df = df.withColumn('json', F.to_json(section))`. The `to_json`  function will serialize struct in each row to json string